# How to type a function of union type's each properties

Tags: typescript

In this type case,
What should the test() function's generic should be?

```
interface A {
    type: 'a' ;
    state: number;
}

interface B {
    type :'b',
    state: string;
}

type OneOfThem = A | B;

function test<T extends OneOfThem>(type: T['type'], state: T["state"]): T {
    return {type, state} as T
}
```

```
test('a', 3) // should not be error
test('a', "asd") // should be error
```

In this case, test function's type are working like

```
function test<OneOfThem>(type: "a" | "b", state: string | number): OneOfThem
```

so both of expressions does not throw errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to distiguish between either of the [Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) Members is by using a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content). Here's one approach using the built in type [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union). Note, that here the generic is a subtype of `OneOfThem["type"]` and not `OneOfThem`.

```
interface A {
  type: "a";
  state: number;
}

interface B {
  type: "b";
  state: string;
}

type OneOfThem = A | B;

function test<T extends OneOfThem["type"]>(
  type: T,
  state: Extract<OneOfThem, { type: T }>["state"],
): Extract<OneOfThem, { type: T }> {
  return { type, state } as Extract<OneOfThem, { type: T }>;
}

test("a", 3); // okay
test("a", "asd");
//        ~~~~~ Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLATwAcIAuZAIjnIG4dkBnMOSMkAVwFsAjaWgXyxZQkWIhQAhTHQLEy5LjTqNmpBmCigA5v0EyUAeRAR9MACoALCB2QBeNMgA%20ycbSww2IBGGAB7EHghGAB5TZAgAD0gQABN6ZENjM0sOAG1yPXIAXQA%20AAppIlVTABolJhZkAFFIqEQwIISTCytizDxCslC%20bLTlSCzSgEoyavU6hqMm5NaMdtlkLuypXCgIMDYof1m9Vr6UPmQ4ONHarwnE5o4ZuaLkbp0sSEZcynJWgGZB6mQAeh-kHwAazg%20EegTALyorUo9Gi5C%20WD%20uGRyIAfuj0WgoJpOBBwACYDdkAByRgaECaYnIYBxEA%20MCHej0YCaEBwLgAGxQYB8yEIcFqHDW0AJROJ7G40GJADosEA)